# Select with joining many-to-many and count one-to-many

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two queries and in one place I need them both. How could I modify the first one?

First (one-to-many):

```js
    const server = await Server.findOne({
      where: { id },
      attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('users.id')), 'localUserCount']],
      },
      include: [{ model: User, attributes: [] }],
      group: ['Server.id'],
      raw: true,
    });
```

Second (many-to-many):

```js
    const serverWithAdmins = await Server.findOne({
      where: { id },
      include: [{ model: AdminUser, as: 'adminUserList', through: { attributes: [] } }],
    });
```

I need something like this:

```js
    const server = await Server.findOne({
      where: { id },
      attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('users.id')), 'userCount']],
      },
      include: [
        { model: User, attributes: [] },
        // New line
        { model: AdminUser, as: 'adminUserList', through: { attributes: [] } }
      ],
      group: ['Server.id'],
      raw: true,
    });
```

But with the last query I got errors like this:

```
"column \"adminUserList.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"
```

I tied to add `AdminUser` attributes to `group` or add `attributes`, but I still can't get an array of `AdminUser` for `Server` like in the second query. Is it a way to use the aggregation function `COUNT` and join another relationship in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn `Sequelize.fn` into `Sequelize.literal` with a subquery and remove `User` from `include` option and `group` option:

```js
const server = await Server.findOne({
      where: { id },
      attributes: {
        include: [
         [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users where Users.serverId=Server.id)'), 'userCount']
         ],
      },
      include: [
        { model: AdminUser, as: 'adminUserList', through: { attributes: [] } }
      ],
    });
```

Comment: Works fine, but you miss `)` for `literal` function and `raw` should be `false`. With `raw: true` I've got `adminUserList.id: 1, adminUserList.role: ...` for the first found relation instead of `adminUserList: [ {id: 1, role: ...} , {...} ]` in the response. You don't know a way to get an object with an array `adminUserList: [...]` for which you can apply a spread operator ({ ...server, arg: 'some' })? `raw: true` breaks an array of `adminUserList`.

Comment: Didn't get the last question. I corrected the answer

Comment: Already got it. I forgot about `toJSON` method. You can't use spread operator for "not raw" sequelize objects because of circular dependency. `toJSON` method solved the problem and you can use `server` variable for something like `{...server.toSON(), isOk: 'true'}` without error `Converting circular structure to JSON`.

Comment: You can just call `get({ plain: true })` for each model instance to get plain objects and after that you can do whatever you want with them